# Social Media using Files in Python returning Errno2

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

So I am working on a mockup social media using file management, and I keep running into this error when attempting to get a user's feed:

```
def getFeed(users=[]):
  global returnVal
  returnVal = []
  for i in range(10):
    with open("database/users/"+str(users[i])+"/posts/"+str(i+1)+".lzs", "r") as f:
      if f.read() == "":
        pass
      else:
        returnVal.append(f.read())
```

this is where the function is being used:

```
while session != None:
  os.system('clear')
  print("LolzSocial\n--------------------")
  print("> 1. View Feed")
  print("> 2. Search User")
  print("> 3. Create Post")
  print("> 4. Logout\n--------------------")
  option = input("What would you like to do?\n> ")
  os.system('clear')
  if option == "1":
    following = "" #none yet
    with open(f"{db_url}/users/{logged}/following.lzs", "r") as f:
      following = f.read()
      if following != "":
        following = following.split(";")
        getFeed(following)
  elif option == "3":
    createPost(input("Write something awesome!\n>"))
```

and this is the exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 121, in <module>
    getFeed(following)
  File "main.py", line 60, in getFeed
    with open("database/users/"+str(users[i])+"/posts/"+str(i+1)+".lzs", "r") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'database/users//posts/2.lzs'
```

Attempted to get user feed, ran into error, and keeps attempting to find a user that does not exist.

Comment: Have you check that file exists `database/users//posts/2.lzs`?

Comment: @Alderven no not yet, but I might add that to the script. The issue is for some reason, the user won't be added to the path, which is why there are two "/" instead of "/username/".